# How can I make the items aligned in section?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, description

I have this code

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, paper=portrait, pagesize=auto]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textit{\alph*)}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FFC296}
\begin{document} 


\section{Student 93b427156c}
\begin{description}
    \item[number] 93b4s27156c              
    \item[name] Note that this analysis of a formative as a pair of sets of features is necessary
to impose an interpretation on an important distinction in language use.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

I want to display them like tables so that the data does not come under the header. So, basically, like two columns, so that headers are on left and content on right in separate columns.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I hope I understood the question correct</sub>

Using the package `enumitem` you can specify the label position and the alignment of the label by `\SetLabelAlign`

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, paper=portrait, pagesize=auto]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FFC296}
\begin{document} 
\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hss\llap{#1\quad}}
\setlist[description,1]{align=rightbox,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=0pt}
\section{Student 93b427156c}
\begin{description}
    \item[number] 93b4s27156c              
    \item[name] Note that this analysis of a formative as a pair of sets of features is necessary
to impose an interpretation on an important distinction in language use.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks buddy , that is working right , but is there any way to make the labels come under STudent and move the description right , so thay all align

Comment: @user17: And the number of the section shall go to the margin? Can you provide a small picture?

Comment: yes u r right , something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/FgjAv.png on top

Comment: @user17: I don't know whether I understand you. Here an example `\documentclass[paper=a4, paper=portrait, pagesize=auto]{scrartcl}\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[3]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#3\autodot\enskip}}\usepackage{enumitem}\usepackage{showframe}\begin{document}\setlist[description,1]{labelwidth=*,leftmargin=2cm,}\section{Student 93b427156c}
\begin{description}\item[number] 93b4s27156c\item[name] Note that this analysis of a formative as a pair of sets of features is necessary
to impose an interpretation on an important distinction in language use.\end{description}\end{document}`